# Passing Gnuplot variables to a shell expression

Tags: shell, gnuplot

I m trying to get the first element of a file within gnuplot:

```
data = "file.dat"
x = `cat data | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'`
```

but this keeps giving me the following error:

```
no such file or directory
```

I should write something like
x = `cat $data | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'`

(with dollar)

Obviouly, this is also not correct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

You need to use a

```
set macro
```

and then use the symbol `@` to get the value of the variable `data`
(`@` in Gnuplot is like `$` in bash)

so this should work

```
x = `cat @data | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Comment: Correct, that works. But one has to keep in mind, that the macro expansion works inside of backticks, but not inside of single and double quotes. To illustrate that, consider the following examples: the expression ``set macros; col="1"; print `echo @col` `` outputs `1`, which is correct, but ``set macros; col="1"; print `echo "@col"` `` quits with an error, because the macro was not expanded. But this is only a side note `:)`.

Answer (score 7):

Another possiblity instead of the backtics is to use the `system` function. Then you can build any string and run it as shell expression:

```
data = 'file.dat'
x = system("head -n 2 ".data." | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'")
```

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally downvoted this answer and when I realized it could not be changed. I have made a trivial edit to amend it.